# How does GCP cloud build "find" the image?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

After reading docs and thinking about it/trying it out I still struggle with the concept.

My understanding of GCP Cloud Build is:

1. It can run bunch of steps as configured by users
2. Each step can use different docker image to run
3. workspace folder (and current folder?) are shared between steps

where I absolutely lost is CBs relationships to the "built" images.
If my script creates a new image in the current folder (e.g. I've used jib plugin and gradle image to build a java project), how does CB "find" it?

I see the options in both jib and docker to push images into a repository (seems to be the standard way?), and it seems to be the way used in sample yamls, but then, what is the point of "images" parameter? What does it do?

Tried scripts like the following:

```
steps:
- id: Test
  name: gradle:7.3-jdk17
  args: ['gradle','test']
- id: Build Docker
  name: gradle:7.3-jdk17
  args: ['gradle','jibBuildTar', '-DBRANCH_NAME=$BRANCH_NAME', '-DREVISION_ID=$REVISION_ID']

images: ['gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/my-project']
```

Comment: Only /workspace is persistent in ClouD Build. So, if you build your JAR and it is in your /workspace, it lives through the steps. In addition, the container images are kept in the Docker service that run on the machine, here again it lives through the steps.

Comment: My thought was that there is a docker daemon available, but... when I ask jib to do "jibDockerBuild" (which, per description, builds to a docker daemon) it complained that it cannot find it.

Comment: As for "only workspace folder lives through the steps", read that, but even google's own examples show otherwise, e.g. this one is accessing jar file in "build" folder.

https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/building/build-containerize-java

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the answer to my question here:

https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema#network

> Cloud Build network When Cloud Build runs each build step, it attaches
> the step's container to a local Docker network named cloudbuild.